Transfermarkt data scrape into Google Sheets for a beginner
I am attempting to pull various bits of data from specific player profiles from Transfermarkt into a Google Sheet. I have read this answer by Mike Steelson to this request, but as someone who doesn't know HTML, I am having a difficult time using Mike's code in different ways.
Would someone be able to explain the different lines of his code? In particular, the .replace line is quite confusing to me:

function rank() {
  var url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/rafael-toloi/marktwertverlauf/spieler/72441'
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { followRedirects: true, muteHttpExceptions: true })
    .getContentText()
    .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, "")
  var regExp = new RegExp(/Ranked number \d+ among all players of the Serie A/);
  Logger.log(regExp.exec(html)[0])
}




As far as my specific implementation goes, I'm looking to retrieve 'Current Club', 'Date of birth/Age', and 'Current Market Value:' from the "profil" page for individual players- so the best url for retrieval is https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/rafael-toloi/profil/spieler/72441 (for the player in question in Mike Steelson's answer)
Any input and help is much appreciated.
I tried replicating the solution to this post
